Parsing to get location title from google maps url
I have a bunch of google maps links and I need to get the title stored in them using parsing
this is an example of the url I have https://www.google.com/maps/place/AlUkhdud+Archaeological+Site/@17.4774955,44.1793098,17z/data=!4m6!3m5!1s0x15fee97a9d578021:0x5ca7bd49ebf31b4c!8m2!3d17.4774955!4d44.1793098!15sCg7Yp9mE2KPYrtiv2YjYr5IBBm11c2V1bQ?shorturl=1
I need to get : AlUkhdud Archaeological Site
update I found a solution!
here's the code: pattern = re.compile(r'/place/([^\+/]+(?:\+[^\+/]+)*)') match = pattern.search(url) if match: location_title = match.group(1) cleaned_title = re.sub(r'\+', ' ', location_title)
I wrote this parsing code to get the title but it's not working properly it's returning the long and lat
pattern = re.compile(r"\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+")
        matcher = pattern.search(url)
        if matcher:
            coordinates = matcher.group(0)
            return coordinates.split(",")
        else:
            return None, None


The regex obviously looks for four numbers. You would obviously need to use a regular expression which actually targets the text you want to extract.

You must have copied the pattern from somewhere because it searches for digits separated by .. Hence the co-ordinates and so irrelevant to your requirement.
Note the site name falls between place/ and /@ so that is used to define the capture group.
pattern =re.compile(r"place/(.*)/@")                                                                    

name = pattern.search(url).group(1).replace('+', ' ')

print(name)

gives:
AlUkhdud Archaeological Site

